# Searching Of Folders in Public Folders by giving its PATH

Tags: c#, api, exchange-server, managed, exchange-server-2010

Is it possible to search for all folders and sufolders in public folders by giving the path of the folders??

Comment: See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561124/searching-of-folders-in-public-folders-by-giving-its-path-name/15276349#15276349

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Get-PublicFolder -Identity <ParentFolderPath> -Recurse
```

For example:

```
Get-PublicFolder -Identity "\NON_IPM_SUBTREE\schema-root" -Recurse
```

Should yield the default folders:

```
Name                                                        Parent Path
----                                                        -----------
schema-root                                                 \NON_IPM_SUBTREE
Default                                                     \NON_IPM_SUBTREE\schema-root
microsoft                                                   \NON_IPM_SUBTREE\schema-root
exchangeV1                                                  \NON_IPM_SUBTREE\schema->root\microsoft
```

Comment: Hi BHall,

Thanks for u reply.I need to do with EWS Managed API.Not with powershell.

Comment: I apologize.  It wasn't clear in the title, but now I see the API and C# tags.  I don't know the programming side of Exchange, just the infrastructure side.  I see that you have answers to your other EWS post, good luck!

Comment: Hi BHall,Tanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

Using:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

is a static class and avoids creating an instance.

See [Directory vs DirectoryInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146586/directory-vs-directoryinfo)
 for more information

Comment: -1: Have a look at the tags. He is asking about folders inside Exchange.