# Searching Of Folders in Public Folders by giving its PATH Name

Tags: c#, web-services, api, exchange-server, managed

Is it possible to search for all folders and sufolders in public folders by giving the path of the folders by using Exchange Web Service(EWS) Managed Api?

Answer (score 10):

You can only search within folders, one level deep on EWS so for:

> PublicFoldersRoot\subjectA\sectionB\partC\

I would search for "subjectA" folder, then once I have that FolderId then I would then search for "sectionB" folder and so on until I find what I need.

The method `GetPublicFolderByPath` takes the path "subjectA\sectonB\partC\" and splits the path into an array of folder names, then finds each folder recursively.

```
public Folder GetPublicFolderByPath(ExchangeService service, String ewsFolderPath)
{
    String[] folders = ewsFolderPath.Split('\');

    Folder parentFolderId = null;
    Folder actualFolder = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < folders.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (0 == i)
        {
            parentFolderId = GetTopLevelFolder(service, folders[i]);// for first first loop public folder root is the parent
            actualFolder = parentFolderId; //in case folders[] is only one long
        }
        else
        {
            actualFolder = GetFolder(service, parentFolderId.Id, folders[i]);
            parentFolderId = actualFolder;
        }
    }
    return actualFolder;
}
```

The method `GetTopLevelFolder` gets the first folder, "sectionA" which is a child of the public folders root a.k.a. "WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot".

```
private Folder GetTopLevelFolder(ExchangeService service, String folderName)
    {
        FolderView folderView = new FolderView(int.MaxValue);
        FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot, folderView);

        foreach (Folder folder in findFolderResults)
        {
            if (folderName.Equals(folder.DisplayName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return folder;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Top Level Folder not found: " + folderName);
    }
```

The `GetFolder` method takes a parent FolderId and searched all of the children folders for a match on the name provides and returns the child FolderId you have requested.

```
private Folder GetFolder(ExchangeService service, FolderId ParentFolderId, String folderName)
    {
        FolderView folderView = new FolderView(int.MaxValue);
        FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(ParentFolderId, folderView);

        foreach (Folder folder in findFolderResults)
        {
            if (folderName.Equals(folder.DisplayName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return folder;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Folder not found: " + folderName);

    }
```

Please note that I am using the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices managed API dll, similar idea for `https://yourexchangeserver/ews/services.wsdl`. To get a folder from the path use create the ExchangeService object then write:
`GetPublicFolderByPath(service, "subjectA\sectionB\partC\")`

Please up-vote if this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wrapper based on @ono2012's answer

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace EmailServices.Web.IntegrationTests
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/jj220499(v=exchg.80).aspx
    internal class MsExchangeServices
    {
        public MsExchangeServices()
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
            m_exchangeService = new ExchangeService { UseDefaultCredentials = true };

            // Who's running this test? They better have Exchange mailbox access.
            m_exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
        }

        public ExchangeService Service { get { return m_exchangeService; } }

        public Folder GetPublicFolderByPath(string ewsFolderPath)
        {
            string[] folders = ewsFolderPath.Split('\\');

            Folder parentFolderId = null;
            Folder actualFolder = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < folders.Length; i++)
            {
                if (0 == i)
                {
                    parentFolderId = GetTopLevelFolder(folders[i]);
                    actualFolder = parentFolderId;
                }
                else
                {
                    actualFolder = GetFolder(parentFolderId.Id, folders[i]);
                    parentFolderId = actualFolder;
                }
            }
            return actualFolder;
        }

        private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
        {
            // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
            bool result = false;

            Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

            // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
            // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
            // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
            if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
                result = true;

            return result;
        }

        private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;

            // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
            if ((sslPolicyErrors & SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) == 0)
            {
                // In all other cases, return false.
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (chain != null)
                {
                    foreach (X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
                    {
                        if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) && (status.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                        {
                            // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid. 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (status.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                            {
                                // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                                // so the method returns false.
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are 
                // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
                // for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
                return true;
            }
        }

        private Folder GetTopLevelFolder(string folderName)
        {
            FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = m_exchangeService.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot, new FolderView(int.MaxValue));
            foreach (Folder folder in findFolderResults.Where(folder => folderName.Equals(folder.DisplayName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                return folder;

            throw new Exception("Top Level Folder not found: " + folderName);
        }

        private Folder GetFolder(FolderId parentFolderId, string folderName)
        {
            FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = m_exchangeService.FindFolders(parentFolderId, new FolderView(int.MaxValue));
            foreach (Folder folder in findFolderResults.Where(folder => folderName.Equals(folder.DisplayName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                return folder;

            throw new Exception("Folder not found: " + folderName);
        }

        readonly ExchangeService m_exchangeService;
    }
}
```